# Why sp_spaceused show nonzero results when the table is empty?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FillFactor](
    [FillFactorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Table doesn't have any primary keys or indexes. First I populate table with dummy data, and then execute procedure `sp_spaceused` where I got one row with some values of reserved data, index data, and so on.

But when I delete all rows from table and execute `sp_spaceused` procedure, I got following result:

[image]

Why are values > 0? What happened with storage space when delete data? Can anyone explain me this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you delete rows from the database, you are emptying the pages that are allocated to the table, in a heap (a table without a clustered index) no pages can be de-allocated from the table without an exclusive table lock, if you did the delete like the below, you will see a different result in your sp_spaceused results:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[FillFactor] 
WITH
(
TABLOCK
)
```

You can still get empty pages hanging around in tables with indexes, but these are usually removed pretty quickly by the ghost cleanup process.

The truncate operation immediately deallocates the pages from the table rather than deleting the rows and hence emptying the pages and so after running that command, you will see all zeroes for sp_spaceused.

Answer (score 0):

But if you TRUNCATE the table then you will get zeroes again. You're seeing the overhead of the pages that the table had populated, but you have emptied with the DELETE statements.